# How to see who shared my link on Facebook

Tags: facebook, sharing

On my Facebook page, I posted a link to my YouTube video. When I was using the Facebook search to find a page, I was surprised to find that my link showed up and it said that 4 people shared it. Is there a way to find out who these people are, and where they shared my link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be limited to seeing **only** the people who shared the link ***publicly*** (according to their privacy settings).

1. Go to http://www.facebook.com/search.php
2. Enter the link or better the title of the link/video title (in case of YouTube video)
3. You will be able to limit the **Posts** results by your friends or everyone (e.g. [example](http://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=5%20Reasons%20Life%20is%20Better%20After%20Age%2030&type=eposts&init=srp))

Comment: If I click on posts by friends, then I can see a few results, but if I click on posts by everyone, nothing comes up. Is that normal? Shouldn't what I see in posts by friends also show up?

Comment: @z-buffer this is the behaviour I am experiencing too. Must be by design...

Comment: The number of posts by friends is nowhere near the number shown in facebook for one of my videos. Does everytime someone comment or like a video count as sharing? Even if those are taken into account, it's still nowhere near the number that is being shown as shared.

Comment: Which number is greater?

Comment: The number shown as shared.

Comment: Makes sense. It most likely shows the total number of times it's been shared but some of those shares are protected (not public) thus you don;t see them as separate entries

Comment: This doesn't work anymore ..

Answer (score -1):

Finding how many shared your link on Facebook is a three step process:

1. you need to own that page to see haw many peoples had shared your link
2. you need to use facebook as you page (in my case [www.facebook.com/zevrat](http://www.facebook.com/zevrat))
3. in the search box type the  part from the title of your link to see the results

Comment: Please do not add signatures to your posts, especially with links. Please review the [FAQ].